# Excel chart showing text over date

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, charts, microsoft-excel-2016

I am trying to show a chart based on a data set similar to this one.
[image]

My intention was to show possible patterns of the Items over a period of dates.

Does somebody know how I can create a chart like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick and easy solution is to use a pivot table and chart:

[image]

Just select your data and click: Insert - Pivot table - Pivot chart.
To set up the chart:

- Set `item` as "legend fields (series)"
- set `date` as "axis fields (categories)"
- for "values" set `count of items`
- right click chart and change it's type to "line with markers"

If you need more sophisticated charts and filters, then best way is probably to copy data from your pivot table to a new location, this way you can chart that more flexibly.